# How to `Raycast` on multiple `Canvas` together for `GraphicRaycaster` in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have several object with `canvas` component, each with it's own `GraphicRaycaster` component too to receive touch event. I use `GraphicRaycaster.Raycast` to test which UI element does the mouse on PC or finger on phones hover on or touching on.

I found that by default a `GraphicRaycaster` can only get results from its own `canvas`. Is there a way to `Raycast` on all `canvas`?

Thank you!

Comment: [Physics.RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) returns all the hits. May that be useful?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay No, not for Graphics (UI) elements

Answer (score 0):

No, afaik you'll have to loop over all of them!

```
PointerEventData yourPointerEventData;

var allHits = new List<RaycastResult>();
foreach(var graphicsRaycaster in FindObjectsOfType<GraphicsRaycaster>())
{
    var hits = new List<RaycastResult>();
    graphicsRaycaster.Raycast(yourPointerEventData, hits);

    allHits.AddRange(hits);
}
```

You could try if it is maybe enough to simply pass in the `allHits` to every raycast call. Not sure if results get appended or the list gets overwritten. But in the docs it is at least called `resultAppendList` so I guess you could simply do

```
var allHits = new List<RaycastResult>();
foreach(var graphicsRaycaster in FindObjectsOfType<GraphicsRaycaster>())
{
    graphicsRaycaster.Raycast(yourPointerEventData, allHits);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Too bad, I'm doing this way too. BTW it's you that answered almost all my question.